# Merging point and polygon in ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, merge

[image]

I have a model in ModelBuilder to perform a merge which is used to iterate through from subfolder 1 to subfolder 32 that looks for the polygon-type shapefile and joins them. However, the model does not work to perform the merge with the shapefile of type line or point, and when the model is executed to perform the iteration in all the folders looking for the shp of type line or point to join them into one, the result shows in screen the last shp of the last folder.

How could I improve my model so that it performs the merge for points or lines?

Comment: You can't merge points or lines with polygon features, an ArcGIS feature class can only store one geometry type

Comment: The step labeled "Merge" is that just a name you gave a join? What kind of join are you doing?